# gcloud vs gcloud beta vs gcloud alpha (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, version, gcloud, alpha, beta

I found there are 3 commands **"gcloud"**, **"gcloud beta"** and **"gcloud alpha"** on **GCP**:

```
gcloud ...
```

```
gcloud beta ...
```

```
gcloud alpha ...
```

I read the GCP documentation about [**gcloud**](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference), [**gcloud beta**](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta) and [**gcloud alpha**](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha) but in my view, these 3 commands are almost the same.

My questions:

1. What is the difference between them?
2. Which is the latest version, middle version or oldest version?
3. Which do I better use?

Answer (score 4):

Gcloud is the main stream for all the GA (Generally Available) API of Google Cloud

Gcloud Beta is for the preview feature, not yet in GA. Normally the API shouldn't change

Gcloud Alpha is for prototype, early access, APIs. The design of API is not final, and can change. Some API can be abandoned.

---

Normally, all the GCLOUD should be in the BETA version also. but GCLOUD is the most recommended.